# Выведите чётные числа

Tags: javascript, инспекция-кода

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 1) continue
  alert(i)
}
```

Такое решение допустимо ?

Comment: Допустимо. Но почему не `for (var i = 2; i <= 10; i += 2) { console.log(i); }`?

Comment: Думаю более правильное решение закинуть числа в массив и вывести его

Comment: Regent :(( сказали правильно, а написали по другому, я только учусь, все пошел в угол плакать :(((

Comment: @xes, если выводится верный результат - значит решение правильно.

Comment: Зачем создавать массив там, где можно обойтись (причем код будет короче, а работать он будет быстрее) без него?

Comment: Если в дальнейшем не подразумевается использование, то полностью согласен

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **Допустимое** решение - решение, которое правильно решает поставленную задачу со всеми ограничениями, которые наложены в условии задачи
- **Оптимальное** решение - допустимое решение, которое потребляет минимальный объем критических ресурсов (памяти, времени, ...)

Ваше решение является допустимым. Как и десяток других. Например, такое

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0)
    alert(i)
}
```

А вот оптимальным будет такое

```js
let min = 1;
let max = 10;
if (min % 2 == 1)
  min++;

for (var i = min; i <= max; i += 2) {
  console.log(i)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Допустимо, конечно, но как-то нелогично - ищем НЕчетные числа, чтобы потом пропустить вывод числа. Результат хоть и одинаковый, но логика совсем не та.

На самом-то деле надо искать четные числа и выводить их:

```js
for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) alert(i)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если код должен выполниться всего и если он точно вам больше не пригодится, то

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
  if (i % 2 == 0) alert(i);
}
```

В ином случае, если его нужно переиспользовать, или число может измениться динамически, то

```js
function even(n) {
  let nums = [];
  for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0) nums.push(i);
  }
  return nums.join('');
}
alert(even(10));
```